# John the Ripper method takes so much time to crack the hashcat file

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat, john-the-ripper

Does John the Ripper method take so much time to crack the password? It's been 3 hours since the process started. No output yet and my PC specs are lower than you think.

Hashcat:

```
Airtel-My WIFI-BMF422-58E4:$WPAPSK$Airtel-My WIFI-BMF422-58E4#k3g06ZXYyCSU66AjYC8Ti4O5HZq0dUZw6JeFlHD/3afwKQH0GV8HVVHlamO6SfXQrrRBlbxcbAJB2XHTsBehfCTrzLIpePzhcJI7RE21.5I0.Ec.............YC8Ti4O5HZq0dUZw6JeFlHD/3afwKQH0GV8HVVHlamM.................................................................3X.I.E..1uk2.E..1uk2.E..1uk0../r2xd/6Yj4PBmW94buZx6pYMNyucO1Y0xiUanrg2gd1Zkt....................................................................................................................................../t.....U...86YxSgREle.YAmr0c0Cu9Y:f8e7a020832f:c05b022258e4:c05b022258e4::WPA2:air01.hccap
```

Comment: No, we can't crack hashes for you. I removed that part of the question.

Comment: If the password is very long and not in your wordlist, then it could take days or weeks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the incremental mode of `john`, the time frame fully depends on the length of the password. A very long password may take weeks, months or even years to be cracked.

This image gives a fun representation of how long it could take under different circumstances: ([source](https://cloudnine.com/ediscoverydaily/electronic-discovery/how-long-will-it-take-to-crack-your-password-cybersecurity-trends/))

[image: Table showing how long password cracking may take for different lengths of passwords]